# simple fadeIn jQuery

Tags: jquery, fadein

I'm trying to make a simple fadeIn fadeOut with jQuery, but it doesn't seem to work..

```js
$("h1").append("<p>This is new.</p>");

// With the element initially hidden, we can show it slowly:
$("#clickme").click(function() {
  $("#square").fadeIn("slow", function() {
    // Animation complete
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="clickme">
  Click me
</div>
<img id="square" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/4963558f-bbaf-419b-9695-abdd14691841%2Fsquare.png?1544000277571" alt="" width="100" height="123">
```

I got this from http://api.jquery.com/fadein/ (I replaced the book image with a square shape image because I don't have the book image)

I am starting JavaScript and HTML and I don't really understand the answers for the other fadeIn jQuery questions, which is why I'm asking my own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start from `display:none` for the `#square` then you can `fadeIn`

```js
$("h1").append("<p>This is new.</p>");
    
// With the element initially hidden, we can show it slowly:
$( "#clickme" ).click(function() {
  $( "#square" ).fadeIn( "slow", function() {
    // Animation complete
  });
});
```

```css
#square {display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="clickme">
  Click me
</div>
<img id="square" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/4963558f-bbaf-419b-9695-abdd14691841%2Fsquare.png?1544000277571" alt="" width="100" height="123">
```

Answer (score 1):

How can you `fadeIn` if the square is alredy faded?

> Use FadeIn when the square is non visible and FadeOut when square is visible.

In this example, the square is `display:none` and when *"click me"* the square **fadeIn**.

```js
$("h1").append("<p>This is new.</p>");

// With the element initially hidden, we can show it slowly:
$("#clickme").click(function() {
  $("#square").fadeIn("slow", function() {
    // Animation complete
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="clickme">
  Click me
</div>
<img id="square" style="display:none" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/4963558f-bbaf-419b-9695-abdd14691841%2Fsquare.png?1544000277571" alt="" width="100" height="123">
```

Answer (score 1):

You fadeIn only element is invisible. Have a look at the below script

```js
$("h1").append("<p>This is new.</p>");

// With the element initially hidden, we can show it slowly:
$("#clickme").click(function() {
  $element = $("#square");
  if ($element.is(':visible')) {
    // Hide if already visible.
    $element.fadeOut("slow", function() {});
  } else {
    // Show if not yet visible.
    $element.fadeIn("slow", function() {});
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="clickme">
  Click me
</div>
<div id="square">
  <img src="https://cdn.glitch.com/4963558f-bbaf-419b-9695-abdd14691841%2Fsquare.png?1544000277571" alt="" width="100" height="123">
</div>
```